# How to test default action in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I was testing redux actions using Jest , When i try to test the default action, it throws an Error

> ```
> Expected value to equal:
>   {"payload": {"male": "mancha"}, "type": "actions/change_gender"}
> Received:
>   [Function anonymous]
> ```

It seems it sends the function, instead of values.

> **test** change_gender.js

```
import changeGender, { CHANGE_GENDER } from '../change_gender';


const payload = {
  type: CHANGE_GENDER,
  payload: {
    male: 'mancha'
  }
};
describe('actions', () => {
  it('should Change the ', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: payload.type,
      payload: payload.payload
    };
    expect(changeGender('male', 'mancha')).toEqual(expectedAction)
  });
});
```

> Action change_gender.js

```
import toggleToolTip from './toggle_tooltip'; // eslint-disable-line

export const CHANGE_GENDER = 'actions/change_gender';


export default(radioType, type) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CHANGE_GENDER,
    payload: {
      [radioType]: type
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the dispatch at `change_gender.js`:

**change_gender.js**:

```
import toggleToolTip from './toggle_tooltip'; // eslint-disable-line

export const CHANGE_GENDER = 'actions/change_gender';


export default(radioType, type) => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: CHANGE_GENDER,
    payload: {
      [radioType]: type
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chen-tai mentioned, returning from the dispatch would help here for testing purposes.

The reason you see [Function] being returned is that your action is a function returning a function.

```
(radioType, type) => (dispatch) => { ... }
```

The first set of params, followed by the fat arrow is an anonymous function. That then returns another anonymous function that takes a *dispatch* function as its arguments. So, if we call the action twice, providing a mock dispatch function, we'll get back the expected action!

```
const action = (radioType, type) => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: "CHANGE_GENDER",
    payload: {
      [radioType]: type
    }
  });
};

console.log(
   action('male', 'mancha')((action) => action)
 )
```

We can then write out test:

**Action change_gender.js**

```
import toggleToolTip from './toggle_tooltip'; // eslint-disable-line

export const CHANGE_GENDER = 'actions/change_gender';


export default(radioType, type) => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: CHANGE_GENDER,
    payload: {
      [radioType]: type
    }
  });
};
```

**test change_gender.js:**

```
import changeGender, { CHANGE_GENDER } from '../change_gender';
const payload = {
  type: CHANGE_GENDER,
  payload: {
    male: 'mancha'
  }
};
describe('actions', () => {
  it('should Change the ', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: payload.type,
      payload: payload.payload
    };
    expect(changeGender('male', 'mancha')((payload) => payload).toEqual(expectedAction)
  });
});
```